# Js mousover event

Tags: javascript

I have a 16 x16 grid, im trying to turn a cell of the grid black on mouseover, ive tried various types of events so I must be messing it up with my labeling?

```
<script>
  // grid creation
  const container = document.getElementById("container");

function makeRows(rows, cols) {
  container.style.setProperty('--grid-rows', rows);
  container.style.setProperty('--grid-cols', cols);
    for (c = 0; c < (rows * cols); c++) {
        let cell = document.createElement("div");
        cell.innerText = (c + 1);
        container.appendChild(cell).className = "grid-item";
  };
};
makeRows(16, 16);
// mouseover black
    let cell = container.getElementsByClassName("grid-item");
        cell.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
        cell.style.setProperty('backgroundColor', black);

});
```

Comment: Could you also share your html code?

Comment: My html is empty other that a div named container above my <script>

Answer (score 2):

```js
const container = document.getElementById("container");

container.addEventListener("mouseover", function(e){
  let el = e.target;
  if (el.matches(".grid-item")) {
    el.style.backgroundColor = "black"; // needs to be quoted unless black is a variable name
  }
});

function makeRows(rows, cols) {
  // @see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment
  let fragment = new DocumentFragment();
  container.style.setProperty('--grid-rows', rows);
  container.style.setProperty('--grid-cols', cols);
  for (c = 0; c < (rows * cols); c++) {
    let cell = document.createElement("div");
    cell.innerText = (c + 1);
    fragment.appendChild(cell).className = "grid-item";
  };
  container.appendChild(fragment);
};
makeRows(16, 16);
```

```css
/* This CSS is just to make the visual example work. */
#container {
  width: 816px;
}

.grid-item {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
}

.hovered {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Instead of adding 256 different event listeners this adds a single event listener to the container which catches the event as it bubbles up the top of the document tree.

Comment: Thank you, I will have to look more into DocumentFragment()

Comment: Did not know `DocumentFragment` either ,awesome! Thanks to this solution we can avoid useless costly DOM manipulation! Love it

Comment: @DanDeGraaf DocumentFragment improves the performance so that the function causes one redraw when we attach the fragment to the DOM instead of 256 redraws as each element is attached. Its not really that complicated - its a like a mock document that you can attach nodes to and traverse but its not actually displayed so it won't cause expensive UI reflows.

Comment: @DanDeGraaf if this answers your question you should accept the answer.